# Blackberry Java: Removing a ListField after it was clicked on, strange behaviour

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, listfield

I have an application that makes use of the ListField component. As items are clicked on in the ListField, I remove the ListField from the manager and add in other managers.

My problem is that the click "event" is being passed to other fields that automatically get focus as a result of the ListField has been removed. So far my only away around this has been to make those controls unfocasable during the time I am switching out components.

Is there a neater way of doing this, having to make all my controls unfocasable for this small time seems like a bit of a hack. Any suggestions welcome.

*Note: in my ListField's navigationClick method I am returning True.*

Comment: Have you considered just switching to another Screen - instead of removing a ListField?

Comment: Yes, but we have an animation that runs in a separate part of the screen as the list changes (think progress through a wizard type indicator). All working now, so thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Manager.replace](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#replace%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29). Remember to prepare both fields before that: remove listeners from old field, add listeners to new field.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the order of events:

1. Add new managers.
2. Set focus where you want it to go.
3. Remove old manager.